# why created_at,update_at not same as my local time gorm golang?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am using gorm http://jinzhu.me/gorm/ to handle database in my golang project. When i update a record, the update_at time is not same as my local time server.
How do i solve it??

Comment: Can't really tell from your question, you should explain better.  Are you talking about time on two different machines?  Different by how much?  Are they set to two different timezones?  Timestamps are often in UTC not local have you accounted for that?

Comment: thanks for answering. I knew my problem. When connect database, i miss "&loc=Local".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found my issue. When connect to database, i miss "&loc=Local" parameter. And it causes my above problem. Thanks for watching!

Comment: Can you provide an example of your solution?

Comment: dns := fmt.Sprintf(
   "%s:%s@tcp(%s:%s)/%s?charset=%s&parseTime=True&loc=Local",
   Username,
   Password,
   Host,
   Port,
   Dbname,
   Encoding,
  )
  var err error
  db, err = gorm.Open(DbInfo().Adapter, dns)
  if err != nil {
   log.Fatalln("connect database failed")
  }

Comment: Hello! Could you help me with the same issue but using PostgreSQL. `loc` parameter does not seem to do something. How to achive saving UTC with portsgres?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the time.Now() used by gorm will be in the UTC zone, to change the default behavior, do the below as mentioned in the official gorm doc.

```
db, err := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("gorm.db"), &gorm.Config{
    NowFunc: func() time.Time {
        return time.Now().Local()
    },
})
```

add like this in config, which will change all the place where time.Now() is used in gorm to local

refer this official doc link [official gorm doc #nowfunc config](https://gorm.io/docs/gorm_config.html#NowFunc)